# Develop spherical (360) panoramic camera like Google Street View in Android

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2, 360-virtual-reality, 360-panorama

I tried searching a lot about developing 360 camera like Google Street View but still not able to reach through the solution.

I tried with the this [panoramagl-android](http://code.google.com/archive/p/panoramagl-android/) but this is not what i am looking for.

So can any one please give me idea or suggest anything to create spherical camera application.

Answer (score 0):

360 images and videos are generally created with dedicated cameras or groups of regular cameras, and the result then 'stitched' together to produce the 360 representation.

The usual way to represent a 360 image or video at this time time is an equi-rectangular projection, similar to the technique used to depict the spherical globe on flat maps of the world.

If you are trying to do this with a regular phone you face the issue that you only have one camera, so you won't get the an image from multiple cameras at the same time to stitch together. This is maybe easier to understand visually - this is an example of a set up to capture multiple views:

[image]

You then need software to 'stitch' the different videos together. There are quite a few options, many being proprietary, VideoStitch is probably the best known at this time: http://www.video-stitch.com/.

Note that this is processing intensive so it nearly always done on relatively high powered servers rather than on mobile devices.